# Is it possible to have several issuers of an Asset?

Tags: assets, trustline, issuing

I would like to use an asset as sort of a "counter". I would have several accounts that get authorized to be counters, and they can create and send assets to a single account that is collecting all the "counts".

From what I understand that would at least require the count collector account to set up trustlines to all the "count" issuers. But the remaining question, as far as I can see, is whether or not you can have duplicate assets "declarations" (aka issuers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

You can have multiple issuers issue assets with the same asset code. In order to achieve this, the "count collector account" would need to create trustlines for the same `<asset_code>` issued by each of issuer accounts. Then the issuer accounts can just send that `<asset_code>` (issued by themselves) to the count collector account to increase the count.

However, there will not be a "total count" displayed by Horizon for the `<asset_code>` in the count collector's account because these assets are treated as different assets since the issuer for each of these assets will be different (even though the `<asset_code>` is the same). To sum up the total count for the `<asset_code>` you will need to do this using custom code (simple for loop over balances).

Comment: Right. I just assumed that an asset is defined as a tuple of code and issuer. But for @Gjermund's purpose, he might only need to count the tokens regardless of issuer. They'd be different assets, but he needn't care.

Answer (score 1):

Would it suffice your needs to have:

- a single issuer
- several distributors seeded with a pool of tokens from the issuer (which can be replenished if necessary)
- a single counter to receive the tokens

Comment: Yes that solves the problem. It is the backup-plan. It is just a bit more overhead than I would like.
I just want to know if the solution outlined in the question is possible or not.